# Guardar clases de objetos en un array

Tags: python, poo

soy nuevo en Python y tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

Teniendo esas clases hacer lo siguiente:

Crear en el programa principal un array en el que se almacenará un instrumento de cada clase.
• Diseñar el método tocarTodos() que acepte por parámetro el array que haga sonar todos los instrumentos.
• El programa principal aceptará por línea de comandos el instrumento que el usuario desea tocar (el nombre o bien Todos). Si hay más de un argumento o bien no hay ninguno, el programa lo detectará como un error.

No se como hacerlo exactamente.
He intentado crear un array para guardar las clases y mostrarlas pero no esta funcionando
No se por donde tirar la verdad

Me podrias ayudar?

Gracias

```
class Instrumento():

    def tocar_todos(self):
        #instrumento=input('dame el instrumento que quieres tocar')
        array=[Percusion,Viento,Cuerda,Clarinete,Flauta]
        for i in range(len(array)):
            print(array[i])


    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento')


class Percusion(Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento de percusion')


class Viento(Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento de viento')



class Cuerda(Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento de cuerda')


class Clarinete(Viento,Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando clarinete')


class Flauta(Viento,Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando flauta')


Instrumento().tocar_todos()
```

Answer (score 1):

El método `tocar_todos()` no accesa ningún atributo ni método interno de la clase `Instrumento`. Eso nos dice que se debe transformar en una función pura.

En general es un error hacer que una clase sea contenedora de si misma; esa información es externa a la clase, y la debes manejar en otro contenedor (una lista, conjunto o diccionario).

También es un error que una clase conozca a sus clases derivadas. La clase `Instrumento` comete ambos pecados: tiene una lista de subclases.

Nada de eso es necesario y la alternativa es mucho más simple.

En primera aproximación, quitando el parámetro `self`, que no se usa, nos queda

```
def tocar_todos():
    array=[Percusion,Viento,Cuerda,Clarinete,Flauta]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(array[i])
```

Pero hay un error ahí. Cuando escribes `Percusion` estás nombrando la clase; lo que necesitamos es un **objeto**, por lo que lo apropiado es escribir `Percusion()` (un objeto particular de la clase `Percusion`).

El `for` también se puede simplificar, usando `for elemento in array:`. Y el `print()` es redundante, pues al función `tocar()` se encarga de hacerlo.

Y `array` debería ser recibido como parámetro, y así poder usarlo para imprimir cualquier orquesta.

Con todo, queda así:

```
def tocar_todos(lista):
    for instrumento in lista:
        instrumento.tocar()
```

Para usar la función, sirva este ejemplo:

```
orquesta = [Percusion(),Viento(),Cuerda(),Clarinete(),Flauta()]
tocar_todos(orquesta)
```

produce:

```
tocando instrumento de percusion
tocando instrumento de viento
tocando instrumento de cuerda
tocando clarinete
tocando flauta

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Código completo

```
class Instrumento():
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento')


class Percusion(Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento de percusion')


class Viento(Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento de viento')



class Cuerda(Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando instrumento de cuerda')


class Clarinete(Viento,Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando clarinete')


class Flauta(Viento,Instrumento):
    def tocar(self):
        print('tocando flauta')


def tocar_todos(lista):
    for instrumento in lista:
        instrumento.tocar()

orquesta = [Percusion(),Viento(),Cuerda(),Clarinete(),Flauta()]
tocar_todos(orquesta)
```

Comment: Perfecta explicacion companero, gracias

Answer (score -1):

Dentro de tu clase `Instrumento`, en la funcion `tocar_todos`, cambia el codigo a lo siguiente:

```py
array=[Percusion(),Viento(),Cuerda(),Clarinete(),Flauta()]
for i in array:
    i.tocar()
```

Estabas haciendo en el for algo bastante raro la verdad.. ten cuidado porque lo que te interesa es coger cada elemento del `array` y ejecutar su funcion `tocar()`